# Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long/ functions.php on line 104

Tags: php, wordpress

Getting this alert..

> Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given in
> /home/physicoolco/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 104
>
> Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given in
> /home/physicoolco/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 106
>
> Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given in
> /home/physicoolco/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 108
>
> Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, object given in
> /home/physicoolco/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 109

Why are these warnings being shown?

line 104 before I changed it:

```
$datemonth = $wp_locale->get_month( date( 'm', $i ) );
```

I was getting the above alert

Line 104 after I changed it:

```
$datemonth = $wp_locale->get_month( date("m/d/y") );`
```

I am getting no alert; just a blank area where the date should be..

Comment: Can you let me know that what is `$i`?

Comment: `$i` is an object, not a timestamp.

Comment: check the date method documentation. Date method requires timestamp as second param. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Do not ask same questions repeatedly, it wont help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43771331/warning-date-expects-parameter-2-to-be-long-object-given

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is the solutions that you navigate to your theme files under  woocommerce/checkout/thankyou.php around line 58 and have it changed from:-

```
<strong><?php echo date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), $order->get_date_created() ); ?></strong>
to:-

<strong><?php echo date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?></strong>
```